# COBOL copybook to .NET

Tags: .net, dictionary, cobol

I have a requirement where a MVC controller should fetch a field from SQL database and then return it to a view. However this is a COBOL to .NET conversion project. I am new to .NET. I have just started taking MVC lessons. The data we store in SQL will be a code for a description. However the view should return the description of the code.

For example the code will be C01. The description on the view will be Wiper blades C01. How do I do this. There are too many codes. Should I create a data dictionary? Can someone help me on how to do this?

Comment: You should find a course on SQL databases first. The storage architecture is completely different. You don't need a data dictionary, the database table is the "data dictionary" - you can have eg a `Categories` table with ID,Name, Description or any other fields you need, store the data you want there and load the data you want by ID or any other condition you want. BTW "smart" keys are not smart at all, so IDs are invariably auto-incrementing numbers. If that `C` has any special meaning, it should go into a separate field

Comment: What about this is COBOL? Where does a copybook come into this?